# .wav chooser, writing sound to the array

Tags: java, arrays, wav, jfilechooser

I choose .wav by using class Frame where I have:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        as = new AudioStream(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Next, I would like to run method below . This method should play .wav and write the sound to an array of bytes, but I have error:

`java.io.IOException: cannot read a single byte if frame size > 1`

```
AudioInputStream stream;
stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Frame.as);
// Get Audio Format information
AudioFormat audioFormat = stream.getFormat();

// Handle opening the line
SourceDataLine line = null;
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,audioFormat);
try {
    line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    line.open(audioFormat);
} catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}

// Start playing the sound
line.start();

// Write the sound to an array of bytes
int nBytesRead = 0;
byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];
while (nBytesRead != -1) {
    try {
        nBytesRead = stream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
        int nBytesWritten = line.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
    }
}

// close the line
line.drain();
line.close();
```

Whats wrong with code?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for [AudioInputStream#read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d,%22int,%22int%29) and [SourceDataLine#write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html#write%28byte%5b%5d,%22int,%22int%29), you'll see that the number of bytes to read/write must be an integral number of sample frames. In your case, it looks like `EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE` is 1 and the audio format must be larger than 8-bit.

Because of the integral number rule, do not create buffers based on a static constant such as you're doing. You've got it almost right by passing `nBytesRead` to `write` but you need to factor in the sample size of the audio. Instead, create your byte buffer with something like this:

```
byte[] abData = new byte[
    audioFormat.getFrameSize() * EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE
];
```

Now your buffer represents a size in integral sample frames.

Comment: Does `getFrameSize` return the size in bytes of a sample in one channel? My assumption was `af.getFrameSize() == af.getChannels() * (af.getSampleSizeInBits() / 8)` (except for `AudioFormat`s with sample sizes wich are not integer multiples of 8).

Comment: What should i modify that i will be ok?

Comment: Just make your byte array larger. Typically something like 500 to 2000 samples is a good number (some systems don't deal well with small buffers). Something like `(frame size) * 1024`. Typically a 'frame' of audio is one sample per channel, so for example for CD-DA (which is 16-bit stereo) the minimum amount you can read/write is 4 bytes at a time.

Comment: i have: private static final int EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 16000*16; byte[] abData = new byte[audioFormat.getFrameSize() * EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE]; and the same error.

Comment: Is the message the same "cannot read a single byte if frame size > 1"? Or different?

Comment: the same  error "cannot read a single byte if frame size > 1"

Comment: Make sure the program's been recompiled and it isn't just running an old version. If your IDE has different buttons for 'run' and 'build', rebuild the project (or even better if there's an option to 'clean' and recompile from scratch). Otherwise I don't see how that's possible since presumably you're not trying to read a single byte anymore. Also according to the JDK source, supposedly that message is only thrown from the no arg read() method. I don't see you using it at all in the OP but make sure you aren't using it somewhere else.